# Android EditText with Arabic numbers

Tags: android, android-edittext, arabic, arabic-support

In my `app` I have `edittext`. Input type is set as `"number"`. Everything works perfectly as long as there is english language set in phone. When we switch language to `"arabic"` user can only enters one input (on `keyboard` we can see numbers like "1,2,3 and so on).

For example, we want to enter number `"23"` . User enters `"2"` and after entering `"3" - "2"` disappears.

Here's xml for my `edittext`

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/offer_edit_text"
        tools:text="$487"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/app_gray"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_huge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```